# iphone dev - Can UINavigationController animate part of the view?

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller

My app is using a navigation controller and it has a navigation bar, a table view and an image  on each view. Those elements layout from top to bottom with no overlapping.

Now because I have the exactly same image for every view (a logo), is it possible to animate only the navigation bar and the table view while the views push and pop? I want the logo always stays on the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea. You might try adding the view directly as a subview of the navigation controller's view, rather than making it part of any of the controllers it manages—in that case, you probably also want to give the view a particular `tag`, then retrieve a reference to it in your individual controllers' `-viewWillAppear:animated:` and call `-bringSubviewToFront:` with it on the navigation controller.

Comment: Based on previous expeirence this should work, the other alternative, is to set your image as the background of the UIWindow and set the views that lay above it to have a clear background